# How can I inject a service in blazor only if it exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

If I use `Inject` attribute and try to inject service that isn't registered, it gives me the error `There is no registered service of type X`.

So how can I inject a service without giving me this error, and if the service isn't injected, the service will be just null. Is this possible?

e.g.

This will give me an error if `Foo` isn't registered.

```
[Inject]
protected Foo Foo { get; set; }
```

But I want to allow that `Foo` isn't registered and in that case it will be `null`.

Comment: This smells like an XY question of course. Expand on why (you think) you need it and you might get better options.

Comment: @HenkHolterman this isn't a XY problem, I can explain why I need this, but I wonder, can you think of a case where you need an optional service?

Comment: At the application level: no, I wouldn't allow that. In a library it might make some sense but I would try very hard to avoid this situation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman you almost got it right.It isn't a library, but a shared kernel for a lot of applications that use blazor in my company. And I'm inject a "global loading" service in my component so it can watch to changes in any loading state of the app and also set it's own loading if need. But what I haven't think of is that not all applications will have this "global loading". 2 applications already use it, but now there will be one that won't use it. So now I need to find a way to continue using it in the component, but don't give any error when that service isn't implemented.

Comment: It's a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/7653)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
@inject IServiceProvider ServiceProvider

@code
{
  private IMyService MyService;

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    MyService = ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();
    base.OnInitialized();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question might make sense if you wanted to access server side data but only if blazor was prerendering on the server side (Blazor WebAssembly App (ASP.Net Core Hosted)).

In situations like this you might be registering services in the ASP.Net app Startup.cs and the Blazor WebAssembly entry point Program.cs.

In cases like this you can create a interface for the functionality you are wanting to access:

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Client {
    public interface IResponse {
        void SetNotFound();
    }
}
```

Have one instance of the interface that does nothing, or returns empty results which can be registered for the Program.cs:

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Client {
    public class ResponseStub : IResponse {
        public void SetNotFound() {
            // Do nothing if we are browser side
        }
    }
}
```

And another instance that does the work with the instance setup in Setup.cs:

```
using BlazorApp1.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace BlazorApp1.Server {
    public class Response : IResponse {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public Response(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
            _httpContextAccessor = accessor;
        }

        public void SetNotFound() {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
    }
}
```